# How to get popularity (likes or checkins) of Facebook Places through the Graph Api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible (and if so how) to get the number of likes (preferred) or number of checkins for Facebook Places in a particular area?

I'd like to use that info to populate a database of populate attractions, restaurants in a particular city.

Any other source (dumps are api's ) that provide such info are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, that would require a number of calls. You'd likely be rate limited if you went crazy with it, but nevertheless here is the solution I see:

1) Get Relevant Places:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000
```

2) Loop through those places, for each call the api again

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PLACE_ID
```

to retrieve this sort of data:

```
  "checkins": 1320,
   "were_here_count": 2671,
   "talking_about_count": 21,
   "likes": 1120,
```

Comment: Ahh great stuff. Couldn't find anywhere that `were_here_count` etc was available.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your request by sending batch of calls in the same request to Facebook
check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests)